# Creating a signup form using a tableview in xcode (like SnapChat)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am looking to improve my app's signup and login form from standard text boxes to using table rows (or something similar).

I am pretty much inspired by the forms which SnapChat have created, which you can see below...

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how they accomplished this, and am thinking it must be a table view with 3 cells (Static?), and the text below is part of the footer of that selection of cells.

How is one able to then capture data into it directly?

Am I right in maybe assuming that each cell is 'custom' with a text field in each one (with placeholder text) with a no-borders style on the text field?

Or has this been achieved via some other way?

Keen to hear your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: May be help this url.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692164/ios-adding-text-fields-to-uitableviewcell-programmatically-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely could do that with a table view. But I don't think this one is. Notice the divider lines start at the far left rather than at 15 pixels in (with the text). The separator lines are also two pixels tall rather than one. So I'd say it's a safe bet that it's just a simple view with 1 pixel tall UIView's for lines.

Comment: Thats a very interesting assumption, and I think you could be right! Just tried to get the same effect using UIViews for separator lines, and it seems to be pretty much spot on. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Dave Batton any reference for this type of design?